# Sylow $p$-subgroup of a direct product is product of Sylow $p$-subgroups of factors

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

> Let $G = H \times K$ be a finite group (direct product), $P$ a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$. Prove that there exist Sylow $p$-subgroups $H'$, $K'$ of $H$ and $K$ respectively so that $P$ = $H' \times K'$

I am very new to the group theory, so can you explain solution properly? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: It's not true. Let $G=S_3$, $H=\langle (1,2) \rangle$, $K=\langle (1,2,3) \rangle$, $P=\langle (1,3) \rangle$ with $p=2$.

Comment: Was the product $HK$ supposed to be direct?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft yes, it supposed to be direct.

Comment: Presumably the problem should be to prove that there exists a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ which is the product of Sylow $p$-subgroups of $H$ and $K$. I am not seeing immediately how to do that!

Comment: Ah right! That explains it! So I wonder what the answer to my interpretation of the question is.

Comment: Please indicate this in the question then. Note that a subgroup of the given form will certainly be a Sylow subgroup, so any given Sylow subgroup will be conjugate to it. What do conjugates of such a subgroup look like?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Conjugates of this group is a direct product of conjugates of $H$ and $K$, right?

Comment: @DerekHolt Hmm, that is a good question. So one would have to somehow pick the conjugation correctly in order to "hit" $H$ and $K$ in the right way.

Comment: Not of $H$ and $K$, no. Of $H'$ and $K'$, yes.

Comment: I came to such result: we can found $H'$ - a Sylow p-subgroup in H, that $H' \subset P$. Then we got that $K' \subset P^g$, for some $g \in G$. Then consider that $g = hk$ for some $h \in H$ and $k \in K$. Then I got stuck

Comment: Remember that $H$ and $K$ are normal in $G$, and if $K'\subseteq P^g$ then $K'^{g^{-1}}\subseteq P$.

Comment: So, $K'^{g^-1}$ will be Sylow p-subgroup in K?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

However, the following is true. Let $G=HK$, $H$, $K$ subgroups and let $p$ a prime dividing the order of $G$. Then there exists a $P \in Syl_p(G)$ such that $P=(P\cap H)(P \cap K)$, with $P \cap H \in Syl_p(H)$ and $P \cap K \in Syl_p(K)$.

**Proof** Let us first find a Sylow $p$-subgroup $P$ of $G$ such that $P\cap H$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $H$ and $P\cap K$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $K$. Let $Q$ be a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $H$ and let $R$ be a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $K$. Choose a Sylow $p$-subgroup $S$ of $G$ such that $Q\subseteq S$. By Sylow theory, there is a $g\in G$ such that $R\subseteq S^g$. In particular, $S\cap H=Q$ and $S^g\cap K=R$. 
But $g=hk$ for some $h\in H$ and $k\in K$. Then $S^g\cap K=R=S^{hk} \cap K=(S^h \cap K)^k$, hence $R^{k^{-1}}=S^h \cap K$ and this is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $K$, being a conjugate of $R$. On the other hand, $S^h \cap H=(S \cap H)^h=Q^h \in Syl_p(H)$, since it is a conjugate of $Q$. So $P=S^h$ is the Sylow $p$-subgroup we were looking for.

Finally we use a counting argument to show that indeed $(P \cap H)(P \cap K)=P$. Observe that $$|(P \cap H)(P \cap K)|=\frac{|P \cap H| \cdot |P \cap K|}{|P \cap H \cap K|}=\frac{|H|_p \cdot |K|_p}{|P \cap H \cap K|}$$
where the $p$-subscript denotes the largest $p$-power dividing a positive integer (which is understood to be $1$ if the integer in question is not divisible by $p$).

Since $P \cap H \cap K$ is a $p$-subgroup of $H \cap K$, note that $|P \cap H \cap K| \leq |H \cap K|_p$. Combining this:
$$|(P \cap H)(P \cap K)| \geq \frac{|H|_p \cdot |K|_p}{|H \cap K|_p}=[\frac{|H| \cdot |K|}{|H \cap K|}]_p=|G|_p=|P|$$ since $G=HK$ and $P \in Syl_p(G)$. As a *set* $(P \cap H)(P \cap K) \subseteq P$, so we conclude $P=(P \cap H)(P \cap K)$.$\square$

Comment: I need to proof that every Sylow p-subgroup of $G$ is the direct product of Sylow p-subgroups of $H$ and $K$

Comment: @Nicky Hekster: is that easy to prove?

Comment: @Derek, I edited with a proof.

Comment: Thanks, that's very nice. I initially thought that was what the question was asking!

Comment: @Derek Holt, me too! That's why I wrote it down!

Comment: You prepared $P$ so that $|H|/|P \cap H|$ and $|K|/|P \cap K|$ are both not divisible by $p$, but why is $|H \cap K|/|H \cap K \cap P|$ not divisible by $p$? I am unaware of a general theorem that if $G = HK$ and $P \in {\rm Syl}_p(G)$ with $P \cap H \in {\rm Syl}_p(H)$ and $P \cap K \in {\rm Syl}_p(K)$ then $P \cap H \cap K \in {\rm Syl}_p(H \cap K)$.

Comment: @user1728 In general, if $P \in Syl_p(G)$, $H \leq G$, then $|H:H \cap P|$ is not divisible by $p$. Why? $|HP|=\frac{|H| \cdot |P|}{|H \cap P|}$, so $|H:H \cap P|=\frac{|HP|}{|P|}$. Since the left-hand side is an integer, the right-hand side must be too, and since $|P|$ is the largest $p$-power dividing $|G|$, $p$ cannot divide $|H:H \cap P|$.

Comment: Counterexample: $G = S_3$, $H = \{(1),(12)\}$, and $P = \{(1),(13)\}$.  Then $P \in {\rm Syl}_2(G)$ and $H \cap P = \{(1)\}$, so $[H:H \cap P] = |H| = 2$, which is divisible by 2.  More generally, if $G$ is divisible by $p$ just once and $H$ and $P$ are distinct $p$-Sylow subgroups of $G$ then $P \in {\rm Syl}_p(G)$ and $H \cap P$ is trivial, so $[H:H \cap P] = |H| = p$, which is divisible by $p$.  Your error is that you need to require $HP$ to be a *subgroup* of $G$. Otherwise $|HP|$ need not divide $|G|$, and without that you can't conclude that $|HP|/|P|$ is not divisible by $p$.

Comment: The reason I knew something had to be wrong is that if $G$ is a finite group and $H$ is a subgroup, there's no general theorem that every $p$-Sylow subgroup $P$ of $G$ intersects $H$ in a $p$-Sylow subgroup of $H$.  There *is* a theorem that this is true if $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, and that's useful because the result is just not true for intersections of Sylow subgroups with arbitrary subgroups.  In general a *conjugate* of $P$ will intersect $H$ in a $p$-Sylow subgroup of $H$, but that conjugate might not be $P$ itself.

Comment: In the notation of your answer, if $(H \cap K)P$ is a subgroup of $G$ then the reasoning you gave in your last comment above would work.  Is $(H \cap K)P$ necessarily a subgroup of $G$?

Comment: @ user1728 Thanks for pointing out the flaw, I repaired the argument, see my edited proof. +1 from me for your remarks.

Comment: The new argument looks good. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Realized that we (with all the comments above) did not answer the OP’s original question fully. So assume $G=MN$, $M \unlhd G$, $N \unlhd G$, with $M \cap N=1$, that is, $G$ is an (internal) direct product of $M$ and $N$. We use the well-known fact that for any $K \unlhd G$, and $P \in Syl_p(G)$, $P \cap K \in Syl_p(K)$, and all Sylow $p$-subgroups of $K$ arise in this way.

The key thing to show here is that for every $P \in Syl_p(G)$ we have $P=(P \cap M)(P \cap N)$. Note that this implies that $P \cong (P \cap M) \times (P \cap N)$.

Observe that $|G|=|MN|=|M|\dot|N|$ and $|(P \cap M)(P \cap N)|=|P \cap M| \dot |P \cap N|$ (remember $P \cap M \cap N \subseteq M \cap N = 1$).

So $|G|$=$ \color{darkblue}{\frac{|M|}{|P \cap M|}\cdot\frac{|N|}{|P \cap N|}}\cdot|(P \cap M)(P \cap N)|$, where the darkblue numbers are not divisible by $p$. It follows that  $|(P\cap M)(P \cap N)|$ $|$ is divisible by $|P|$, and hence $P=(P \cap M)(P \cap N)$. The line of proof is similar to my other answer here on this page.

Note that if one would start from an *external* direct product, the proof would be somewhat simpler, by noting that the direct product of the Sylow $p$-subgroups of each of the factors, gives a Sylow $p$-subgroup of the whole group.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that we can prove everything using the fact that Sylow $p$-subgroups are *maximal* $p$-subgroups (by [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylow_theorems)).

Let $G = H \times K$ and let $P$ be a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$. Consider the projections  onto each coordinate of the direct product:

\begin{align}
\pi_1 : H \times K &\rightarrow H, \quad
\pi_2 : H \times K \rightarrow K
\\
(h,k) &\mapsto h, \quad
(h,k) \mapsto k
\end{align}

Notice that $P \leq \pi_1(P) \times \pi_2(P) \leq G$. But $\pi_1(P) \times \pi_2(P)$ is a $p$-group (see note below) and so since $P$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup (and thus is maximal), we must have $P = \pi_1(P) \times \pi_2(P)$.

Now let's show that $\pi_1(P)$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $H$ and $\pi_2(P)$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $K$.

Without loss of generality, suppose $\pi_1(P)$ is not a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $H$. Since $\pi_1(P)$ is a $p$-subgroup (see note below), then in particular our assumption implies that it is not maximal in $H$. Then there exists a $p$-subgroup $Q \leq H$ with $|\pi_1(P)| < |Q|$. But then $Q \times \pi_2(P)$ is a $p$-subgroup of $G$ with

\begin{align}
|P| = |\pi_1(P) \times \pi_2(P)| < |Q \times \pi_2(P)|
\end{align}

But this is impossible, because $P$ is maximal.

---

Note: I have used the following [general property of elements of direct products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_product_of_groups#Elementary_properties):

\begin{align}
|(h,k)| = \text{lcm}(|h|,|k|)
\end{align}

So in particular, if $|(h,k)| = p^n$ for some $n$, then we know that both $h$ and $k$ must have order a power of $p$.

Answer (score 1):

I will be using your notation. Since $G$ has direct factors $H$ and $K$ , the  elements of $H$ and $K$ commute, which particularly means elements of $H'$ and $K'$ since they are subgroups of $H$ and $K$ respectively. Therefore, $ H'K'=K'H'$ which implies that $H'K'$ is a subgroup (see [Prove that $HK$ is a subgroup iff $HK=KH$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1197732/prove-that-hk-is-a-group-iff-hk-kh)). Since  $|H'K'|=|P|$ , $H'K'$ is a Sylow-$p$ subgroup.