# Let $G$ be a group and $H,K \le G$,then - If $H \le N_{G}(K)$ then $HK \le G$ - If $H \le K$ then $ C_{G}(K) \le C_{G}(H)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$  be a group and $H,K \le G$,then show that:

- If $H \le N_{G}(K)$ then $HK \le G$
- If $H \le K$ then $ C_{G}(K) \le C_{G}(H)$

Where $C_{G}(H)$ is the [centralizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centralizer_and_normalizer#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20especially%20group%20theory,that%20satisfy%20a%20weaker%20condition.&text=of%20the%20ring.-,The%20centralizer%20of%20a%20subset%20of%20a,is%20a%20subring%20of%20R.) of $H$ defined as:

$${\displaystyle \mathrm {C} _{G}(H)=\{g\in G\mid gh=hg{\text{ for all }}h\in H\}.}$$

And $N_{G}(K)$ is the [normalizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centralizer_and_normalizer#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20especially%20group%20theory,that%20satisfy%20a%20weaker%20condition.&text=of%20the%20ring.-,The%20centralizer%20of%20a%20subset%20of%20a,is%20a%20subring%20of%20R.)  of $K$ defined as:

$${\displaystyle \mathrm {N} _{G}(K)=\{g\in G\mid gK=Kg\}.}$$

---

For the first part I have that:

$N_G(K)$ is the normalizer of $K \le G$.  It's the set of all $g$ such that $gKg^{-1} = K$.

Since $H \subset N_G(K)$, then for all  $h \in H$ we know that they commute  with $K$ like the $g$. Hence for all $h$ in $H$ we have that $hK = Kh, $  which means $HK = KH$.

On the other hand from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1197732/prove-that-hk-is-a-subgroup-iff-hk-kh) link we see that $HK \le G$,as desired.

The second part is the part that I don't know how to prove,I know that for $H \le K$ we have that $C_G(H)<N_G(H)$,but does that help?

Comment: This is almost trivial: if an element centralizes $K$ then since $H$ is a subset of $K$, it centralizes $H$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take an arbitrary element $c \in C_G(K)$. We want to show that $c \in C_G(H)$.

Note that $c \in C_G(K) \implies ck = kc, \forall k \in K$. But since $H \le K$, we have $ch = hc, \forall h \in H \implies c \in C_G(H)$.