# Sylow subgroup of a group generated by two subgroups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory, finitely-generated

Let $G$ be a finite group and $H=\langle A ,B\rangle$ be a subgroup of $G$ generated by subgroups  $A$ and $B$ of $G$. Is it true that $H_r=\langle A_r,B_r\rangle$, where $H_r$, $A_r$ and $B_r$ are Sylow subgroups of $H,A,B$ respectively.

Comment: Use `\langle` and `\rangle`, not `<` and `>`

Answer (score 4):

No, take $G=H=S_3$, $A=\langle (12)\rangle$, $B=\langle (13)\rangle$.
Note: it is true when $H=AB$, see [Sylow $p$-subgroup of a direct product is product of Sylow $p$-subgroups of factors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/610094/sylow-p-subgroup-of-a-direct-product-is-product-of-sylow-p-subgroups-of-fact)

Comment: (Just to clarify, here $r=3$.)

Comment: @verret: or it could be $r=2$; because then $\langle A_r,B_r\rangle$ wouldn’t even be a $2$-group...